# Array decreasing with Array.lenght

Tags: java, arrays

I can't get into the for iterations neither can see the error, while trying to make a for from the max size to 0

Thanks for ur time

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner recibe_datos = new Scanner(System.in);     
        int number=1;
        int size=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("set size"));
        int[] array= new int[size];
        int size_test = array.length;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,array.length);
        for (int i = size_test; i >= 0; i--) {

            array[i]=number;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Position: "+i+" value: "+array[i]);
                   number=number+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't start at size_test. An array the size of n have indexes from 0 to n-1, so start from size_test-1

Comment: thanks a lot, it was so basic but i learned some new today, thanks

Comment: Note that different programming language start at different base index https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array)#Indexing there's also somewhat confusing VB.NET where the index starts at 0, but to help VB6 programmers, the declaration syntax define the upper bound instead of size. Make sure to read the documentation for the language you're learning.

Answer (score 1):

For an array if the size is 10 that means the array index will be 0-9 and array.length will return you the value 10 for your index you need to start it from 9. so in your code you can start your loop like

```
for (int i = size_test-1; i >= 0; i--) {

        array[i]=number;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Position: "+i+" value: "+array[i]);
               number=number+1;
    }
```